# only show price inclusive VAT on product page

Tags: magento2, vat, product-prices

My regular prices are exclusive VAT.

Only on the product page I want to show exclusive VAT and inclusive VAT.

I tried to change it via:

> Stores->Configuration->Sales->Tax->Show product prices in catalog->inclusive
>   and exclusive VAT

Then there are 2 problems:

1. It shows the inclusive and exclusive VAT price on the whole website but I only want to show it on the product page.
2. I want it to show the price exclusive VAT and on the bottom of this price the inclusive VAT price. Not otherwise.